# Writing & testing a PatchAsJsonAsync request in a .NET 7.0 Minimal API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

**Writing the Implementation**

Let's pretend I have a `Person` object:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

My `Program.cs` file has the following minimal API endpoint

```
app.MapPatch("/people/{id}", MapApiEndpoints.UpdateAge)
```

And then the execution occurs in my `MapApiEndpoints` class:

```
public class MapApiEndpoints
{
    //

    internal static async Task<Result> UpdateAge(int id, int age, PersonDbContext db)
    {
        var personToUpdate = await db.People.FindAsync(id);
        if (personToUpdate is null) return TypedResults.NotFound();
        personToUpdate.Age = age;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync()

        return TypedResults.NoContent();
    }
}
```

**Testing the Patch Request**

How do I then test this endpoint? My test approach currently looks like this:

```
public async Task GivenAge_ThenPersonisUpdatedWithAge_AndSavedToDatabase()
{
    // Create new Person
    // save new Person to database

    var newAge = 30;
    var updatePersonAgeResult = await _client.PatchAsJsonAsync($"/people/{:id}, new  
        {
            age = newAge
        }
    ); 

    // get Person from database using same Id
    // Assert whether Person.Age = newAge
}
```

The main confusion is how you pass along a `new { }` object with the `PatchAsJsonAsync` method.

Comment: Why are you defining a `PATCH` action method that doesn't accept a JSON patch request-body? - or enable the client to specify exactly which properties to set? As your method _always_ overwrites the `.Age` property your method should be `PUT`, imo.

Answer (score 1):

The `UpdateAge(int id, int age, ...)` handler will bind `age` parameter from query, so you will need URL like `/people/1?age=42`.

If you want endpoint to accept a JSON body then you should create a model for it, for example:

```cs
public record UpdateAgeRequest(int Age);

internal static async Task<IResult> UpdateAge(int id, UpdateAgeRequest request, ...)
{
    // ... implementation
}
```

Which will need the JSON body with `age` property:

```cs
var updatePersonAgeResult = await _client.PatchAsJsonAsync($"/people/{id}", new  
{
    age = newAge
});
```

Read more:

- [Parameter Binding in Minimal API apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0)